# Flutter not Launching, Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, visual-studio-code

Although it is a standard flutter program and works in Chrome, when I want to run it on Android, the following debug gets stuck in the console and does not give any response or errors. The program does not work??

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge3zc.png)

I think there is no problem in Android Studio. I turned it off and on and applied wipe data. but I couldn't get it to work

Comment: Are you tried to wait several minutes? For the first time it can take a time

Answer (score 0):

Starting on Chrome is easier than a phone emulator. In other saying, the Android emulator requirement is heavier than the Chrome browser in Flutter. Your picture shows the normal routine of Launching. If you wait enough time it will start. If your computer has a performance mode it makes it easy.